# Удаление временных файлов в Temp

Tags: c#

Решил написать программу которая будет удалять временные файлы которые старше n-дней. Программа файлы удаляет, но есть одно НО, те файлы которые заняты другим процессом, при нахождении таких файлов программа падает. Добавил try - catch что бы ловилось это исключение, программа перестала падать, но на найденном файле, который используется другим процессом, перебор файлов останавливается и не идет дальше. 
Как сделать что перебор файлов не останавливался на первом найденном файле который занят другим процессом а перебирал дальше все остальные файлы в папке?

Вот код который написал:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int delDay = 10;

        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\Temp");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-delDay))
                {
                    fi.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: "перебор файлов останавливается и не идет дальше" Потому что в try-catch нужно пихать не полностью цикл, а только удаление файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проверку переместить в цикл:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int delDay = 10;

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\Temp");
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        if (fi.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-delDay))
        {
            try
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```